# PHP/MySQL Insert distinct array values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, unique-constraint, distinct-values

I am inserting values into a MySQL table using the code below, and I need to prevent users from inserting the same `priority` value for each `studentname` more than once. What is the best way to do this please?

This is the table:

```
 id         studentname    title         academicdiscipline  priority    
012345678   TEST, NAME     Test title 1     Civil                1
012345678   TEST, NAME     Test title 2     Civil                2
012345678   TEST, NAME     Test title 3     Civil                3
012345678   TEST, NAME     Test title 4     Civil                4
012345678   TEST, NAME     Test title 5     Civil                5
```

Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {
  $ids = $_POST['id']; 
  $names = $_POST['studentname']; 
  $titles = $_POST['title'];  
  $disciplines = $_POST['academicdiscipline']; 
  $priorities = $_POST['priority']; 

foreach($priorities as $key => $priority) { 
    if ($priority > 0) { 

        $query = "INSERT INTO flux_project_selection (id, studentname, title, academicdiscipline, priority) 
            VALUES ( " . mysql_real_escape_string($ids[$key]) . ",
            '" . mysql_real_escape_string($names[$key]) . "',
            '" . mysql_real_escape_string($titles[$key]) . "',
            '" . mysql_real_escape_string($disciplines[$key]) . "',
            " . mysql_real_escape_string($priority) . "  )";

         $retval = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
                            } 
                        } 
                echo "<p> Added.</p><br />"; 
}
```

Comment: create index for unique record, using combination of fields

Comment: you can create it like `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD UNIQUE INDEX index_name (field1, field2);` and so on.

Comment: @RamSharma thanks - worked `ALTER TABLE flux_project_selection ADD UNIQUE INDEX (studentname, priority);`great - It inserts the first row and give a 'Duplicate entry ... for unique index'. I'd like to prevent the insertion and give a warning so they can go back and check selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create index for unique record, using combination of fields

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD UNIQUE INDEX index_name (field1, field2);
```

it will allow you to add first record but on duplicate entry show Duplicate entry ... for unique index. You can either use `try and catch` to display error message or use `on duplicate update record` if your project has this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

query for the max priority for the student then increment it with 1.

```
$queryMaxPriority = 'select max(priority) from flux_project_selection  where id = STUDENT_ID;

$priority_no = $queryMaxPriority + 1;
```

i used this in some of my apps i developed.

**Update**

```
 $priority = 'select count(priority) from flux_project_selection where id = STUDENT_ID and priority = PRIORITY'; 

if (count($priority>0)){
 //send some error message in your page. 
}
```

Comment: How does this determine whether the `priority` inputted is a duplicate?

Comment: But you're also essentially making the `priority` field's value arbitrary instead of user-defined, aren't you??

Comment: ah ok. you want your priority to be user inputted. then you just check if piority already exist for that student. $priority = 'select count(priority) from flux_project_selection  where id = STUDENT_ID and priority = PRIORITY; if count is greater than zero then it means it has error and need to be redirected back to your form.